# How do I make EF exists query?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have two lists `rtrn` and `Zipcodes`

rtnr items have a `Utility` field. I need to return a subset of `rtrn` where `rtrn.Utility` exists in `field1` or `filed2` or `field3` of `zipocode` item

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the unique utilities from this zipcodes fileds 1-3

   ```
       DbSet<Utility> utilities;
       DbSet<Zipcodes> zipcodes;

       var uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes = zipcodes.Select(x => x.Field1).ToList();
       uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes.AddRange(zipcodes.Select(x => x.Field2).ToList());
       uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes.AddRange(zipcodes.Select(x => x.Field3).ToList());

       uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes = uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes.Distinct().ToList();
   ```
2. Intersect unique utilities with zipcodes

   ```
       uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes = uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes.Distinct().ToList();

       var zipcodesWhereUtilityExistsInAnyUtiltyField = utilities.Intersect(uniqeUtilitiesInZipcodes).ToList();
   ```